# Classic ASP xsl date conversion

Tags: xslt, asp-classic

I have the following code that reads a rss feed into my page, but I would like to have the pubDate convert into a more human readable date if alt all possible.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?><!-- DWXMLSource="mm_news.xml" -->
  <!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet]>
  <xsl:output method="html" encoding="iso-8859-1"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <p class="newsList-date"><xsl:value-of select="pubDate"/></p>........
```

This gives me:

```
  Fri, 9 Sept 2011 15:21:36 GMT
```

but Would Like to read something like

```
  Friday 9 Sept 2011
```

Even be happy if I could simply trim off the end to just have 'Fri, 9 Sept 2011'

Also if easier can I add an extra section within the xml so i can simply enter the date like I want it so I can read it, something like below? (The xml is hand written not dynamically created)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="US-ASCII" ?> 
    <?xml-stylesheet title="XSL_formatting" type="text/xsl" href="direct.xsl"?>
    <rss version="2.0">
    <channel>....

    <item>....
    <title>.....
    <description>....
    <thedate>.....
```

Many Thanks

Comment: why have you used the xsl-fo tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the quick & dirty way would be to substitute `select="pubDate"` for an expression like this:

```
select="substring(pubDate,1,16)"
```

That one's dependent on the month being four letters however, and only gives you your 'fallback' result of 'Fri, 9 Sept 2011'.

If necessary, you can be a bit cleverer and remove the requirement of the month being four letters (which seems unlikely for May), by using this expression:

```
select="substring(pubDate,1,string-length(substring-before(pubDate,':'))-3)"
```

Rather than taking a fixed length of 16, it bases it on where the first `:` is (in the time), and subtracts 3 from that.

If you REALLY want, there's a one-line expression that can give you what you want, but it's a bit convoluted:

```
select="concat(normalize-space(substring('Monday    Tuesday  WednesdayThursday Friday   Saturday Sunday   ',string-length(substring-before('MonTueWedThuFriSatSun',substring(pubDate,1,3))) * 3 + 1,9)),substring(pubDate,5,string-length(substring-before(pubDate,':'))-7))"
```

This uses a 'lookup', to find where the day of the week exists in one string, and uses that to pick the full name from another, finally using 'normalize-space' to trim any extra spaces. Then it just concatenates it with the date part.

Comment: Thanks for this I had a similar one to the first using replace and removing the time and date, but looking at yours and especially the second one it worked well, thanks